# Map Reduce/Sum using Underscorejs

Tags: json, underscore.js

I am trying to convert the following dataset:

```
var data = {
"csrf": "token",

"items": [
{"category": "product1", "image": "image1.jpg", "cost": "$6", "item_totals": [
    {"category": "discount", "amount": "-$1.0"}]
},
{"category": "product2", "image": "image2.jpg", "cost": "$8", "item_totals": [
    {"category": "discount", "amount": "-$1.2"}]
}],

"totals": [
{"category": "shipping", "amount": "$0.00", "name": "Shipping", "is_zero": true},
{"category": "taxes", "amount": "$0.00", "name": "Taxes", "is_zero": true}
],
"total": "$1234", "subtotal": "$1234", "id": abc123, "currency_code": "USD"}
```

into a single value, being the sum of all 'amount' values in the item_totals array(s). I cannot seem to do this whilst accounting a varying amount of records in 'items' & for empty 'item_total' arrays. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
  "csrf": "token",

  "items": [{
      "category": "product1",
      "image": "image1.jpg",
      "cost": "$6",
      "item_totals": [{
        "category": "discount",
        "amount": "-$1.0"
      }]
    },
    {
      "category": "product2",
      "image": "image2.jpg",
      "cost": "$8",
      "item_totals": [ // multiple item_totals
        {
          "category": "discount",
          "amount": "-$1.2"
        },
        {
          "category": "discount",
          "amount": "-$1.2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "product2",
      "image": "image2.jpg",
      "cost": "$8",
      "item_totals": [] // empty item_totals
    },
    {
      "category": "product2",
      "image": "image2.jpg",
      "cost": "$8"
      // absent item_totals
    }

  ],

  "totals": [{
      "category": "shipping",
      "amount": "$0.00",
      "name": "Shipping",
      "is_zero": true
    },
    {
      "category": "taxes",
      "amount": "$0.00",
      "name": "Taxes",
      "is_zero": true
    }
  ],
  "total": "$1234",
  "subtotal": "$1234",
  "id": "abc123",
  "currency_code": "USD"
}


var totalAmount = _.chain(data.items)
  .map(item => item.item_totals || []) // emit totals
  .tap(console.log)
  .reduce((memo, bucket) => memo.concat(bucket), []) // collect (flatten)
  .tap(console.log)
  .map(total => parseFloat(total.amount.replace('$', ''), 10)) // emit amounts
  .tap(console.log)
  .reduce((ret, amount) => ret + amount, 0) // collect (sum)
  .value();
console.log(totalAmount);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
```

Comment: any idea why, when I try add this value to a discount value posted in 'totals' array, it concatenates? To note, I added .toFixed(2) for formatting. Thanks!

Comment: Probably because either of those are strings. You can only perform arithmetics on numbers. You will need to convert that to number with something similar to what I did in 'emit amounts' step, add numbers and then format it as string (if necessary).

Comment: Thanks weirdan - I worked out that toFixed returns a string. So had to add this after the addition was made. You're a legend.